What is the [origin] tag for? Retag to [etymology]
Beside the fact that the origin tag has no usage guidance, isn't it a synonym of etymology?
The term "etymology" means:

(the study of) the origin of a word and the historical development of its meaning.

It effectively encompasses discussion around the origin of something.
Sanity check: are there questions about origins that can not be tagged etymology? I feel the answer is no, unless what is being discussed is not a word. Though we can consider the following:

origin of characters is covered by the glyph-origin tag
origin of other non-word language features is probably covered by specific tags, e.g. origin of a chengyu -> chengyuhistory or similar
origin of other non-language items is probably going to be off-topic

Furthermore the origin tag has only 10 questions (I just edited it out of a few), against the 300+ of etymology. So I feel we could retag origin to etymology and burninate it without regret.

"completed" in the sense of "burninated", I guess.

There are only 9 questions, so let's just look at them all:

The "original" proverb of "Craftsman, know your tools"  Not an etymology question.  Actually, doesn't even suit an origin tag, since it's not asking about origins.

Thank You : 谢谢 vs 感谢 vs 跪谢 vs 多谢  It seems to suit the difference tag.  The tags culture and origin seem to be words the OP thought of at the time of writing the question, and are not very relevant.

Where was the heartland of the pre-historic Chinese branch of languages (or that of the entire language family)?  The history tag seems adequate.

Where did the words for various colours originate from?  Definitely etymology is adequate.

Colloquialism - "I go to school by bus"  Again, etymology is adequate.  (It could use a better title.)

what's origin of the Chinese character for time?  Again, etymology is adequate.  (If you're bumping this one, can you also please fix how it describes 时间 as the "character for time"?  时间 is a word [not a single character].)

Radicals vs glyph origins (specifically for character 肚 in 肚 子)  Here glyph-origin is fine (it even contains the word "origin").

What's the meaning/reason for sudden influx in usage of English word "word" in Chinese?  I guess there's an argument for origin on this one, but it feels like it could survive without it.

What is the origin of 洋罪?  Here etymology seems not only suitable, but necessary.


In my opinion, it seems fine to burninate this tag through sensible retagging.  (When retagging and bumping questions to the front page, I encourage you to make other useful edits to the question and its answers.)

Thanks for this summary, all of it makes sense to me. I'll wait maybe one day, to give others the opportunity to chime in, in case we're missing something

aaaand... done. [origin] has zero results. I've also edited a bunch of other content along the way. There's a few quite interesting questions among those
